# How do I mount an ISO and remount using the same mount point to a different ISO in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mount, iso-image, cd

It helps to give my problem some context. I want to install some software on a laptop that doesn't have a CD drive. The installation media composes of 4 CDs installed in series.

What I did was created 4 iso images from the real media and transferred them to the laptop I want to install it on. Windows 10 File Explorer automatically mounted the first disk image when I opened the iso file. I started the setup program and waited for the prompt to enter the next disk in the drive. I then ejected(unmounted the image) using file explorer and opened the next iso. Problem appears to be that windows opened the next image using a different mount point or identifier, because when i return to the running installation software, it still believes the second installation cd to be unavailable. Note that the drive letter in use was the same, because I unmounted the previous iso first. File explorer of course shows the media mounted under a different drive id of style [drive letter - random numbers].

So, I'd like to know if there is a way to mount an iso disk image to a specific drive ID / mount point that can be remounted to another image such that it appear as literally the same drive?

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure of this but is it possible to mount all of the four ISO image files in file explorer before you start the setup program and see if setup works

Comment: This answer does not make logical sense.  It is not possible to mount an ISO, within Windows 10, and assign all 4 ISOs the same drive letter.  The setup is looking for additional files, during the installation process, having 4 different drives would not solve the author's problem.

Comment: Ramhound is correct. Mounting all four ISO images simultaneously doesn't work. I suspect that the setup program wants the CD loaded into the same exact logical drive. I still haven't found a working solution for this.